# How to upload file to Amazon S3 pre-signed URL in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3

I have a pre-signed URL generated for Amazon S3 file upload. How to upload a file to that URL in Laravel using it's HTTP Client (Preferably using the PUT method)?

Comment: Hey did you find an answer?

Comment: Yes, posted the answer to this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying out several ways, I found using Curl to be the best solution.

I used the "ixudra/curl" composer package to make the HTTP PUT request.

My solution:

```
$response = Curl::to(url)
            ->withFile( 'data', path_to_file, '*' )
            ->withContentType('multipart/form-data')
            ->put();
```